# Can I access debian server through bluetooth PAN via SSH access

Tags: ssh, debian, linux, bluetooth

Hi I have an old pentium machine which I want to turn into a server. I have got a debian 6 squeeze distro with me. My machine doesnot have a LAN port on it. I don't want to give access to my server over internet. I only want to use it as a web server for internal testing. My question is can I connect it over bluetooth PAN network as I have got a bluetooth dongle through which I used to connect my desktop to laptop similarly to a LAN network? If so how?

Comment: Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

http://wiki.maemo.org/Bluetooth_DUN

and:

http://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser